# update field from another database SQL Server

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm with a little problem. I have two databases the first is `Gym` and the second is `Prod`:

```
Gym:
----------------------
Tabela orders:
----------------------
Cod_Product
Name
-----------------------

Prod:
-----------------------
Tabela Products:
-----------------------
Id
Name
----------------------
Tabela CodProdutos:
----------------------
Cod_prod
id_prod
--------------
```

The necessary here is to update the field from the table Products equal to the field Name of the table orders of the database gym.

I want to connect the table orders from gym to table codprodutos from the database Prod and then connect to my table called Product, that way I'm gonna update row to row and not give the first row of table orders to all rows of the products.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Which database management system?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using .NET, you're probably also using SQL Server, so this should work:

```
UPDATE Prod.dbo.Products SET Name = (
    SELECT Name FROM Gym.dbo.orders WHERE Cod_Product = (
        SELECT Cod_prod FROM Prod.dbo.CodProdutos WHERE id_prod = Prod.dbo.Products.Id
    )
);
```

If you're using SQL Server , then you're presumably using a single instance to host both databases.  In that case, you would be able to use the following syntax to distinguish between tables in either instance:

```
<database name>.dbo.<table name>
```

`dbo` just sort of means "database object", which can be a table, stored procedure, view, that sort of thing.  So if you say:

```
    Prod.dbo.Products
```

it means:

```
table "Products", from among the database objects in the database "Prod"
```

Oftentimes you can get by with just using a table's name by itself, because you'll often be meeting two conditions:

1. You're only messing with one database within the same query.
2. You're also using what's known as a "default catalog", which is the database SQL Server will assume if you don't tell it a database to look in.

If you're using the default catalog `Prod`, then SQL Server will take this:

```
SELECT * FROM Products
```

and automatically treat it like:

```
SELECT * FROM Prod.dbo.Products
```

You mentioned .NET and VB.NET in the tags for your question, so I'm pretty confident it is SQL Server you're using.  In that case, things like an IDE or Management Studio or something may be sort of auto-selecting a default catalog without necessarily telling you.  But if you want to work multiple databases into the same query, that's probably the holdup you're running into.